# servicemix custom repository not downloading jars

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix

I am running servicemix 5.0.4. I have to use my own repository and not the internet maven repository. I did these steps

config:edit org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn

config:propset org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories http://repo.xyz.com@snapshots ( i need snapshots)

config:update

But Still, not able to download the features when i run features:install.

What is the correct way to specify the repository URL. If my repos is repo.xyz.com. Are there any other things to add to the URL apart from just giving repo.xyz.com.

Comment: You must probably add `@id=something`, e,g, `http://repo.xyz.com@snapshots@id=xyz`

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ksobkowiak

It worked by changing the repository URL  to something like repo.xyz.com/xyz/content